# How to read in .txt file line by line to binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Im trying to make a binary search tree and read in a text file line by line as a node for each line e.g.:

```
Dave Smith 0728492940
Ed James 0956294587
```

So that then I can get the user to enter a name "Dave" and it will bring up their full name and phone number. I just am not sure how to implement reading the text file in to a binary search tree line by line to create a node for each line. At the moment I am just printing out the text file without putting it into the BST.
Code so far is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} ;

//tree wrapper structure
struct tree {
    struct node *root;
} ;

typedef struct tree Tree;
typedef struct node Node;

//create a new tree
Tree *new_tree() {
    Tree *t = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    t->root = NULL;
    return t;
}

//create a new node
Node* NewNode(int data) {
  Node* node = malloc(sizeof *node);
  node->data = data;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;

  return(node);
}
//insert in to the binary tree
Node* insert(Node* node, char *data) {
  // 1. If the tree is empty, return a new, single node
  if (node == NULL) {
    return(NewNode(*data));
  }
  else {
    // 2. Otherwise, recur down the tree
    if (*data <= node->data) node->left = insert(node->left, data);
    else node->right = insert(node->right, data);

    return(node); // return the (unchanged) node pointer
  }
}
//search for nodes to see if they exist
bool NodeSearch(Node* node,int data) {
    if(node==NULL) return false;
    else if(node->data == data) return true;
    else if(data  <= node ->data) return NodeSearch(node->left, data);
    else return NodeSearch(node->right, data);
}

int main(){

    FILE *f;
    char s[1000];

    f=fopen("phone.txt", "r");
    if(!f)
        return 1;
    while (fgets(s,1000,f)!=NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to search for either first name, last name or phone number (don't store those as integers by the way, that makes you loose the initial zero), then you actually need *three* trees: One with the first name as key, the second with last name as key, and the third with phone number as key. The good thing is that you can use the same structures and functions for all trees. Oh, and you should definitely read more about [self-balancing binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

Comment: Your struct defines what data your tree will hold. Current it holds `int data;`. You need to change that to hold the type data you need to store (e.g. *first name*, *last name*, *number*). In your `while (fgets(s,1000,f)!=NULL)` loop, you need to parse the line into the data to store in each node, then call *insert node* to add the node to the tree. I haven't verified your tree code, but you need to work on your reading/parsing the data in `s` first.

Comment: can you be more specific about how you want to perform your partial name matching? in BSTs you usually search with the full key, so your particular requirements are important for an answer. for example matching a substring that's included somewhere in your key is another task from matching only a prefix, and another still if you want to allow for typos, etc...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I don't want to factor for typos or anything, just that if the user inputs a word e.g. "smith" then it prints all the nodes that contain that word.

Comment: what does *contain* mean for you: can it be part of the name, i.e. for a query `lisa` should `elisabeth` turn up or not? once you've written down what your search should be able to differentiate, you'll understand the requirements for your datastructure.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios yes, so for that query that you gave as an example, it should include that and print that string.

Comment: then a BST is not the right tool for that, lookup `suffix tree`

Comment: First of all you need to add `#include <stdbool.h>` otherwise for `bool` ,`false` , `true` compiler will generate error even though you include -std=c99.

Answer (score 0):

> if the user inputs a word e.g. "smith" then it prints all the nodes
>   that contain that word.

There is no point in using a binary search tree if you need to search *within* (part of) the keys; you can use a simple array just as well.